# How to search the web including meta tags

Tags: web, search-engine, meta-tags, google-custom-search, advanced-search

All search engines only find the content with in the body tag as per our search query. I would like to search the  web including meta tags. Cause I'm eager to know who is using what kind of meta tags.

In short I like to search the web page content in other words source , that is with in `<html>` and `</html>` tags including meta tags and other links(css, js) with in the  tag, not just the content with in the **body** tag.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Lol.. google doing that all ... Its silly question.. All worlds using in building your site are searchable. If u want to find exactly one word u must use it with "word" - example `https://www.google.pl/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22stackoverflow%22`

how to search google - https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/134479?hl=en

Comment: Please read my question once, I have asked to search the pages including <head> part. In search results we will only get the content searched/filtered from the <body> tag only

Comment: In formal search, search engine only search the content from <body> tag and will display results to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got what I am looking for, here is the search engine to search source code on web. The search engine for source code. So we can find the what kind of meta tags are being used by others

[nerdydata.com](http://nerdydata.com/)